# Primeng Angular styles on subdomain don't work

Tags: angular, nginx, iis, primeng, cloudflare

I have an Angular application that is hosted on an IIS server, uses Nginx as a proxy server, and its subdomain was created with Cloudflare.
My problem is that this application uses Prime Ng but the styles do not work, however when I host this application on another Hosting such as firebase the prime ng styles work.

Any explanation and solution for this?

I tried to host it on Firebase Hosting with the aim of clearing up doubts if the problem was due to poor import of prime ng CSS styles, however on that hosting it does work. Does not work when hosted on IIS, Proxy Server and Cloudflare SubDomain, styles are not rendered.